# Referencing xaml dictionary resources from pages in a class library

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary

I'm having a little problem with Merging dictionaries in my WP7 application, The app contains a lot of pages and the loading time exceeded the market place limit which is 5 seconds, I had to put the majority of the pages and UI stuff in a separate class library to cut off the loading time, the problem is that the pages ware referencing static resources in the global app.xaml, I tried to move the xaml stuff in App.xaml to a separate resource dictionary in the class library project. I also referenced that resource dictionary file in every page.

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <Converters:TimeSpanToWeekAndDayConverter x:Key="weekAndDayConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

The problem is that I always receive this exception :
Failed to assign to property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source'.

I also tried to change the build action of that resource dictionary from Page to Resource to Content (With all their specific path syntax considerations) without any luck. 
I hope someone has a idea.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think you need to move the resources - you can keep them in the App resources. It should work.
2. You need to reference the dictionary by using the full name. In this case:

   Source="/AssemblyName;component/Resources.xaml"

Otherwise, it won't know how to find it.

Comment: When I say "AssemblyName" in my example, you need to give the actual AssemblyName you are using for your library. Also, please make sure you are correctly marking the type of the resource file as a Page in properties.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I used the full qualified syntax and made the build action to page but didn't work, I'm really confused ! strange !!

Comment: And you are not getting any other errors when the app starts? Can you add some test code at the end of you app's constructor to access some resource that's inside that resource dictionary? Something like object o = Application.Resources["someKeyFromResourcesXaml"]

Comment: Thanks, it seems like that I had a problem with the styles declared inside the resource dictionary, thanks buddy for your help